# Need help to stop data duplication with C#

Tags: c#

I have a system which inserts some recopies into a table. The thing is when I click the update button repeatedly it insert duplicate records into my database. Please help me to fix it.
Note: When I try to use the data in the table, these duplicate data does crash the program.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        (sender as Button).Enabled = false;


        string ItemCode;
        string ItemDesc;
        string ItID;
        string InItID;
        decimal EntQty;
        string EntUOM;
        decimal TQty;
        string NewRec;
        bool Prt;


        TQty = 0;

        foreach (DataRow RowVal in dataSetMaster.ITEM_LINE)//
        {
            ItemCode = RowVal["InITCode"].ToString();
            ItemDesc = RowVal["InITDesc"].ToString();
            ItID = RowVal["ItemID"].ToString();
            InItID = RowVal["Ingredient_ItemID"].ToString();
            EntQty = Convert.ToDecimal(RowVal["Entry_Qty"].ToString());
            TQty = Convert.ToDecimal(RowVal["T_Qty"].ToString());
            NewRec = RowVal["NewRec"].ToString();
            EntUOM = RowVal["Entry_UOM"].ToString();
            Prt = Convert.ToBoolean(RowVal["Print"].ToString());

            // MessageBox.Show("Items in the grid " + ItemCode + " == " + ItemDesc+" /"+Convert.ToString(EntQty)+" / "+Convert.ToString(TQty));


            string ComdTextItemCode;
            string ComdTextItemCodeInsert;
            string Itcode;
            Itcode = TextBoxCode.Text.Trim();
            string X1;

            X1 = "TEST";
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            if (NewRec == "True")
            {

                Guid newGuid;
                Guid newGuid2;


                if (Guid.TryParseExact(ItID, "D", out newGuid))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to a Guid", ItID);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a Guid",
                                      ItID);
                }

                if (Guid.TryParseExact(InItID, "D", out newGuid2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to a Guid", InItID);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a Guid",
                                      InItID);
                }

                //   MessageBox.Show("Test");


                Guid ItmID = newGuid;
                Guid IngItmID = newGuid2;
                Guid GuItem_LineID = Guid.NewGuid();


                //INSERT INTO ITEM_LINE (Item_LineID,ItemID,Ingredient_ItemID,Entry_Qty,Entry_UOM) VALUES (convert(uniqueidentifier, @Item_LineID),convert(uniqueidentifier, @ItemID),convert(uniqueidentifier, @Ingredient_ItemID),@Entry_Qty,@Entry_UOM)

                ComdTextItemCodeInsert = "INSERT INTO ITEM_LINE (Item_LineID,ItemID,Ingredient_ItemID,Entry_Qty,Entry_UOM,[Print],T_Qty)" +
                "VALUES (convert(uniqueidentifier, @Item_LineID),convert(uniqueidentifier, @ItemID),convert(uniqueidentifier, @Ingredient_ItemID),@Entry_Qty,@Entry_UOM,@Print,@T_Qty)";
                sqlInsertItemDtl.CommandText = ComdTextItemCodeInsert;

                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@Item_LineID"].Value = GuItem_LineID;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@ItemID"].Value = ItmID;            // roleID;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@Ingredient_ItemID"].Value = IngItmID;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@Entry_Qty"].Value = EntQty;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@Entry_UOM"].Value = EntUOM;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@Print"].Value = Prt;
                sqlInsertItemDtl.Parameters["@T_Qty"].Value = TQty;

                sqlDADetail.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
           else
           {
               ComdTextItemCode = "UPDATE ITEM_LINE SET ITEM_LINE.T_Qty=" + @TQty +",ITEM_LINE.[Print]='"+ @Prt +
                  "' WHERE ITEM_LINE.ItemID=convert(uniqueidentifier,'" + ItID + "') AND ITEM_LINE.Ingredient_ItemID=convert(uniqueidentifier,'" + InItID + "')";
               sqlUpdateDtl.CommandText = ComdTextItemCode;
               sqlDADetail.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            sqlConnection1.Close();


        }

        MessageBox.Show("Material Master updated.");


    }
```

Comment: you should: add indexes/constrains to database (to make sure that it is impossible to store duplicates in database), then disable UI button during previous click event not finished, and check for existing data in click event to avoid to send duplicates.

Comment: the thing is i am unable to make changes to this table.

Comment: soo, you can ```disable UI button during previous click event not finished, and check for existing data in click event to avoid to send duplicates.```

Comment: The update SQL is in the wrong place in the code.  You should first try insert with int itemsEntered = sqlDADetail.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  Then if itemsEntereded = 0 (item already in database then update.  The database would also need to be modified to set a primary key for ItemID.

Comment: already disable the button. yet i cant properlly catch  a way to handle